# How to create a report of zip code of 6 digits?

Tags: reporting, formula, formula-field, filters

I have a requirement to create a report that will filter and display all Address from Account that have a zip code of 6 digits.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a formula field on the object that is LEN(Zip code) that returns the number of characters. Then, in your report, you can add a filter for that number equal to 6.

Comment: Which is kind of unfortunate, because formulas can cause a full table scan-- this can definitely impact performance of the report.